# Objective-c trace the cause of rendering in SceneKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile, scenekit

I am currently developing a mobile application with SceneKit. [SCNSceneRendererDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate?language=objc) is being used now to render the scene once a call back happens. Since I actually don't want the scene to be rendered in real-time, I turned [rendersContinuously](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/2867339-renderscontinuously?language=objc) of the scene off, and assume the render call back will only be triggered when some visible component changes. However, the problem is that I still found that [render:updateAtTime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate/1522937-renderer?language=objc), which is also the first stage of the render cycle, will always be called after a period of time without any interaction from me. Is there a way to trace back the cause of the call back in Objective-C with XCode so I can no what is triggering the render call back? Any response will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

I used debugger from XCode, but it didn't give much help since most of them are binaries.